# Update field when function finishes its calculations

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got this function that calls an external service, works the results and then returns a single variable. 
I want this variable to be inserted into an input but I'm doing something wrong cause instead of updating the form at the end of the function (as expected) I have to call the function a second time and the code updates the field with the value of the FIRST execution...
**This is the controller:**

```
    $scope.cercaClienteNomeCognome = function() {
    if ($scope.nome == undefined){
        var name = "";
    } else name = angular.uppercase($scope.nome);
    if ($scope.cognome == undefined){
        var surname = "";
    } else surname = angular.uppercase($scope.cognome);
    var url = "servizi/getClienteNomeCognome?nomeCliente="+name+"&cognomeCliente="+surname;
    esitoRicercaEstesa = TreeService.avviaRicercaEstesa(url);
    if (esitoRicercaEstesa == "true") {
        vm.cercaSecondario = TreeService.getProClie();     // THIS_LINE
    }   
    };
```

*vm.cercaSecondario* is the field that I'm trying to update.

**This is the service:**

```
service.avviaRicercaEstesa = function(url) {
    service.url = url;
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        service.apriModaleEstensioneRicerca(data);  
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            toaster.error("[SERVIZIO RECUPERO CLIENTI] Errore durante il ritrovamento dei clienti");            
    });
}

service.setProClie = function (pro_clie) {
    service.pro_clie = pro_clie;
}

service.getProClie = function () {
    return service.pro_clie;
}
```

Example: I run the code for the FIRST time. Everything goes fine. 
When I get to THIS_LINE the field doesn't update.
I then run the code for the SECOND time and when I get to THIS_LINE the field updates with the value from the FIRST execution...... 
What am I doing wrong?! 
I've even tried using $timeout and $evalASync but with no success...

Comment: Where is the code for `TreeService`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your service caused this problem. Try to use $q and return promise from your service. Then use it like this

```
$scope.cercaClienteNomeCognome = function() {
    if ($scope.nome == undefined){
        var name = "";
    } else name = angular.uppercase($scope.nome);
    if ($scope.cognome == undefined){
        var surname = "";
    } else surname = angular.uppercase($scope.cognome);
    var url = "servizi/getClienteNomeCognome?nomeCliente="+name+"&cognomeCliente="+surname;
    esitoRicercaEstesa = TreeService.avviaRicercaEstesa(url);
    if (esitoRicercaEstesa == "true") {
        TreeService.getProClie().then(function (cercaSecondario) {
          vm.cercaSecondario = cercaSecondario;
        });
    }   
    };
```

Comment: doesn't work. It says "TreeService.getProClie(...).then is not a function"

Comment: because your service doesn't return promise. Look at this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q and rewrite your service

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
TreeService.getProClie()
.then(function(res){
   vm.cercaSecondario = res;
})
```

EDIT:
This to work you have to set your service to return promise.

```
.service('TreeService', function($q){
var data = this;
data.getProClie = function(){
var defer = $q.defer();
$http.get('example/url')
.success(function(res){
   defer.resolve(res)
})
.error(function(error,status){
defer.reject(error);
})
return defer.promise;
};
})
```

Comment: nope. It doesn't work. It says "TreeService.getProClie(...).then is not a function"

Comment: Replace .then with .success it should work
Edit: as @donquixote said. You have to set your TreeService to return promise

Answer (score 0):

My bet would be that your remote call will make your code to be "out of angular context" so what happens is that by the time you get your response from your remote call angular won't know this and won't digest. So you either need to manually call `$scope.$digest()` after `vm.cercaSecondario = TreeService.getProClie();` or you can wrap your remote call into `$q.when(remoteCall).then(...)`. This way angular will digest by it's own.

Comment: I've already tried using $digest but the console throws an exception stating "action already in progress"

Answer (score 0):

write `getProClie` function in this way.
You need to promise chaining

```
service.getProClie = function () {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    defer.resolve(service.pro_clie);
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Then in controller :

```
TreeService.getProClie().then(function(data){
    vm.cercaSecondario = data
},
function(){
   //error handling
});
```